# RSS Ajax jquery and IE 9 issue

Tags: xml, jquery, rss, internet-explorer-9

Does anyone know why this code works fine in all but IE9?

```
function showReel(rssLink){
clearGrid();
$(this).load(rssLink, function(event){
    var xml = event,
        objsArray = [],
        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
        $reelxml = $( xmlDoc ),
        $items = $reelxml.find( "item" );

    $items.each(function(){
        var itemObj = {};
        var eachItem = $(this);

        itemObj.company = eachItem.find( "title" ).text();
        itemObj.movLink = eachItem.find( "link" ).text();
        itemObj.thumb = eachItem.find( 'media\\:thumbnail:eq(1), thumbnail:eq(1)' ).attr('url');

        var credits = eachItem.find( 'media\\:credit, credit' );
        credits.each(function(){
            if($(this).attr('role') == "title") itemObj.tit = $(this).text();
            if($(this).attr('role') == "director") itemObj.director = $(this).text();
            if($(this).attr('role') == "editor") itemObj.editor = $(this).text();
        });

        objsArray.push(itemObj);

        var movStuff = $('<div class="picButt"><span class="pic"><img src="'+itemObj.thumb+'"></span></div>');
        movStuff.click(function(event) {
            $('#qt').empty();
            $('#qt').css('display', 'block');
            $('#qt').append('<iframe src="'+itemObj.movLink+'"></iframe>')
            logit("clicked "+itemObj.movLink)
        });
        movStuff.data(objsArray)
        $('#grid').append(movStuff);
    });
});
```

}

locally I get the error

> 'XML5632: Only one root element is allowed.'

In live it won't play at all and I get the error

> 'SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

jquery.min.js, line 2 character 21784'

Using un-minified jQuery it errors on line 1725 caharacter 5, which refers to this if statment

```
if ( !id ) {
        // Only DOM nodes need a new unique ID for each element since their data
        // ends up in the global cache
        if ( isNode ) {
            elem[ internalKey ] = id = ++jQuery.uuid;
        } else {
            id = internalKey;
        }
    }
```

specifically this line:

> elem[ internalKey ] = id = ++jQuery.uuid;

Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.